# slf4j logback log rolling creating .tmp file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have a issue where sometime log rolling creating a .tmp file and does not create the original log file back. interesting I noticed this happens when rolling of logs start 1 min before the midnight.

1.7.15

my logback.xml configuration is as below

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${COMPONENT_LOGDIR}/abc.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${COMPONENT_LOGDIR}/abc.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>750MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${logPatternMdc}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different rolling policy seemed to have fixed the issue. please refer to working config below:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${COMPONENT_LOGDIR}/otm-rest.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${COMPONENT_LOGDIR}/otm-rest.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>750MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>15GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${logPatternMdc}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```